# How to execute server script which is using Express in usual JavaScript script?

Tags: javascript, php, express, server, routes

I am newbie in express, so maybe that is a dumb question, but still: I have js script (called client.js), where I call php script (called mail.php) via fetch(), and php script sends an email. What I need is to call a script which uses express (called server.js) before fetch, so this script would generate an image I will later send in php script.

So here's the fetch in client.js:

```
fetch(`${server}/dist/php/mail.php`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'preferences': purchase,
        'logo': newObject,
        'mail': document.getElementById("email").value,
    }),
})
```

And here is the server.js:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process"),
      express = require("express")

const PORT = 4200
const app = express();

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`What's my age again? ${PORT}, I guess.`);
});

exec("node conf.js", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

So as you see, I call another js script called conf.js using exec(), which actually creates a file I need to send in php script.

The main question is: how can I call server.js before fetch, so it would create a file, and only after that fetch would work? Thanks a lot to any answers.

Comment: Why have you got an express backend _and_ a PHP backend? That seems to be over-complicating things. Choose one server side language and stick to it, would be my advice personally

Comment: Yeah, the thing is, I tried to generate file on php side, but it didn't work, so it works only on js, and I need to use exec() function, and it seems I can use it only with server.

Comment: If something didn't work in PHP, the thing to do would be to fix it rather than starting a whole other backend. PHP can generate files, so it's unclear specifically what your issue was. And your JS isn't generating a file either, according to what you've shown

Comment: It's calling a conf.js script in exec() function, and this conf.js generates an image